# Making anchor tag's "hitbox" the same width as the entire li

Tags: jquery, html, css

First let's provide some context: http://dev.eduantech.com/

There's a preview of my currently-being-developed new website. :) Shameless self promotion. ;P

Anyway, what I want you to put your attention in is the menu, notice how if you hover on the `li` the background goes blue, same as the text, so it's no longer readable. At this point the text should go white, but it doesn't until you actually put your mouse on top of the text (which is the actual `a` tag).

How can I do it so that when I hover on the `li` it actually makes the text white as well. Of course this could possibly easily be achieved with jQuery, but then comes the next question.

How can I make it so that when I click the `li` it starts sending me to the `a` tag's value. In other words, make the entire `li` tag a link...

For you that are interested, I'm using [Statamic](http://statamic.com/).

Again this could possibly all be achieved with some simple/difficult jQuery, can't imagine doing it without jQuery (*shivers*).

If you need any kind of knowledge of my code, you can of course check the website's source and stuff. ;)

Comment: Definitely don't need JS here, CSS only solution

Comment: For the li sending to the a tag's value, should encapsulate `<li>` in `<a>`. For example : `<a href="profile.html"> <li> Profile </li> </a>`.

Comment: @MisterJ Thanks for the idea. I did try that, but notice I have hidden `ul`s for sub-menus, so I can't do that, I already tried. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your `a` tag the same size as the `li`:

```
div#sidebar nav ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

You may also want to remove the padding from the `li` and instead apply it to the `a`

Comment: I went along with your solution since it's the one that works more like I want it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
#menu ul li:hover a{color:#FFF;}
```

Comment: Yep - the more specific the CSS rule the greater precedence it has over other rules.

Comment: Actually, in this answer be careful - the :hover pseudoclass has been applied to the `li` when it should be added to `a`. Although this will work it might not be supported in older brwosers

Comment: This would indicate that you are hovering over the link when in fact you might not be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I went along with @BillyMathews answer since it works more like I want it to. But thanks nevertheless. :)

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way would be make the li tag redirect to the anchor tag's URL. This way, even if you want to have other elements within the li you can click on the entire li element.

Check this experiment here: http://jsfiddle.net/ypJ8Q/

```
$("#clickable").click(function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
});
```